# Manipulations of polynomials with lists

Tags: c

Here are my functions and structures, what does not work is the
derivative and value at the precise point `void Derivee`, 
`float Valeur`. I work with lists, of course.

```
get_at(polyliste* p, int index ,float* coeff,int* deg)

typedef struct node* Node;
typedef struct node
{
    float coeff;
    int degree;
    Node next;
} node;

typedef struct
{
    Node head;
} polyliste;

polyliste create()
{
    polyliste p;
    p.head = NULL;
    return p;
}
float Valeur(polyliste p, float x)
{

    float s = 0, coeff;
    int i = 0, degree;

    while (get_at(&p, i, &coeff, &degree) == 0)
    {
        s = s + (coeff * power(x, degree));
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nLe resultat est : %f", s);
    return s;
}

void Derivee(polyliste *p, polyliste *s)
{
    int i = 0, degree;
    float coeff;
    *s = create();

    while (get_at(&p, i, &coeff, &degree) == 0)
    {
        if ((coeff != 0) && (degree != 0))
        {
            coeff *= degree;
            degree--;
            add_first(s, degree, coeff);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, please take the [tour] and read this: [ask]. Then you need to [edit]  your question and provide a [mcve] and an example of input and expected output.

Comment: `add_first()` definition missing.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: my program doesnt work , example of input 3X^2+2X+1 it would give me 6X+2

Comment: Jihane.j, What is wrong with `6X+2`?  What is the goal?

Comment: Perhaps it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: and for the function Valeur , it just remplaces the X in the polynom with the number x , and calculates the results : x= 2 ; 3(2)^2+2(2)+1

Comment: the goal is i give it a polynom and it returns the deriviate of this polynom thats all , as its in the example

Comment: int add_first(polyliste* p, int degree, float coeff){
    Node n = (*p).head;

    if((*p).head != NULL){
        n = (Node)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        n->coeff = coeff; n->degree = degree; n->next = (*p).head;
        (*p).head = n;
    } else {
        (*p).head = (Node)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        (*p).head->coeff = coeff; (*p).head->degree = degree; (*p).head->next = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: And please learn how to *edit your question* to add code or other crucial information (like the input to your program, the expected output, and the actual output). Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).